# Retrieve ADA from a UTXO address linked with my ADA account on Ledger

Tags: utxo, ledger

[image: Cardano multiple "To" addresses]

I sent ADA from an exchange to Ledger, to an address listed as part of a set of addresses used as the receive address for a previous transaction.

I chose one of these multiple "To" addresses to be the receive address for this new transaction, and it seems the address I chose out of the set was a UTXO address and not the main receive address of the previous transaction.

I can see this UTXO address on the block chain, containing the amount sent. Is there a way to retrieve the ADA sent to this UTXO address?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a Ledger so I'm not quite sure. But here's how it usually works:

- Your wallet has multiple addresses
- You can use any of them to receive ADA
- You can send ADA from any of the addresses as long as there is at least 1 UTxO on it
- It is also possible to send ADA from multiple UTxOs on multiple addresses in one transaction

To answer your question: Yes, it should for sure be possible to spend the ADA on this address.

Unfortunately I don't know how you'd do this in the Ledger UI. Maybe this article can help you: https://support.ledger.com/hc/en-us/articles/6200626140957-How-to-send-a-Cardano-ADA-transaction-with-Ledger-Live?docs=true

If you can't do it with the official Ledger software, try using a Cardano wallet and connect your Ledger to it.

- Here's how to connect to Eternl wallet: https://support.ledger.com/hc/en-us/articles/6433454118685-Connect-your-Ledger-Cardano-ADA-account-to-Eternl?docs=true

Comment: Can send ADA out of Ledger, but the available quantity does not include the latest inflow which was sent to a utxo address (one of the eight "To" addresses shown in the screenshot).

Will experiment with an Eternl wallet and see, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Further investigation suggests I sent my ada to another user accidentally, because this user's address showed up in my list of "To" addresses due to being batched up in the same transaction id by the exchange used. Will seek support from the exchange to retrieve funds.